# How can winsock distinguish unicast and multicast data on the same port?

Tags: sockets, winsock, multicast

I'm using Winsock2 to develop my app. In my case, the source device will send both unicast and multicast UDP datagrams to target device over the same port. On receiving end, I created 2 sockets, one for receiving unicast datagram(named as socket1) and the other for receiving multicast(named as socket2). Socket2 is added into the assigned multicast group. The problem is that since the 2 sockets bind to the same port, socket2 would receive the unicast datagram which is supposed to be received by socket1.

I tried to bind socket2 to the multicast IP address while socket1 still binds to local IP address, but the binding operation failed for socket2. I saw in some threads here they said binding to multicast IP address is not supported on Windows but supported on Linux/BSD. Is this true? Is there any documents or info telling this?

And if binding to multicast IP address is not supported on Windows, how can I distinguish unicast and multicast datagrams on the same port by using some IP level or socket level options? Or I have to make specific filter rules to achieve this?

Thanks!

Ryan

Comment: This is actually a really interesting question. I know nothing about Winsock, my experience is only with the BSD sockets API, but might it be possible to inspect the destination address of the IP headers for the packet? It's kind of dirty, but maybe effective?

Comment: Are you sure you really care which it is? And in any case why not just use a single socket? That's clearly the intention, hence the single port.

Comment: to EJP: I'm afraid I have to care about the type of transmission, so I want to distinguish them when receiving the datagram (either by using 2 different sockets or using single socket). If using single socket, I think the only solution to distinguish them is to analyze the destination address in IP header, but just like Matt Patenaude said, it's kind of dirty. Do you have any good idea to address this issue?

Comment: I don't agree that Matt's suggestion is 'kind of dirty' at all. It tells exactly and unambiguously what you want to know. The only alternative is examining the payload.